# Convert a Microsoft Word doc file to HTML file using ASP.NET & C#

Tags: asp.net

How do I convert a Microsoft Word doc file to HTML file using ASP.NET & C# without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace, as this requires Microsoft word to be installed in the server?

Comment: Do you mean .doc (pre-Office 2007) or .docx (Office 2007)?

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option to use an [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) API instead of Word, since OpenOffice is free? If so, take a look at [this forum post](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=37877) and the links in the first answer.

PS. I got there via [Google](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=openoffice+api+c%23)...

Answer (score 1):

Aspose would be the answer.
http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to open a word document inside a web browser (this may need certain plugins) then somehow capture the raw output of the rendered HTML.

I think Google Web Toolkit has features that opens Words/Excel natively inside a browser?